# WPF DispatcherTimer останавливается с большой задержкой

Tags: c#, wpf, таймер

Доброго времени суток.

Есть форма WPF, и код на C#, который запускается при нажатии на кнопку:

```
        static DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        short ticksInMilliseconds = 0;

        private void timerBeforeHideWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerHideWindow);
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
            timer.Start();
        }
        private void TimerHideWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ++ticksInMilliseconds;
            if (ticksInMilliseconds <= 200) {
                MainBorder.Opacity -= 0.05;
            } else {
                timer.Stop();
                ticksInMilliseconds = 0;
                MainBorder.Opacity = 1.0;
                WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            }
        }
```

Проблема вот в чем: MainBorder по задумке должен стать невидимым(Opacity = 0.0) за 200мс, затем - окно сворачивается, возвращает нормальную прозрачность элементу MainBorder и стает неактивным. Однако таймер при выполнении условия останавливается не сразу, из-за этого окно еще около 1-2 секунд остается активным.

Перепробовал кучу вариантов, как сделать так, что бы таймер останавливался сразу. Может я что то делаю не так? =)

Заранее сердечное спасибо!

Comment: WPF поддерживает анимации прямо в разметке, попробуйте - это более подходящий вариант. Не надо запускать таймеры какие то свои в UI потоке, от этого вы кроме тормозов ничего не получите.

Comment: Была такая мысля, но вот пролема, такое затухание у меня в двух случаях происходит. Либо во время сворачивания окна, либо сворачивание и закрытие программы, то есть свой titleBar вместо Windows.

Comment: и я не хочу в двух частях кода на две кнопки пихать одно и то же затухание
в xaml нет такой штуки как функции и процедуры

Comment: Вы делаете совершенно все не так. Вы работаете с WPF, как с WinForms, где за UI отвечал разработчик, где он кодом прописывал все сам. WPF в первую очередь, это XAML, во вторую очередь, это Binding механизм. С этими двумя вещами вы можете сделать на чистом XAML всю вашу реализацию, и она будет во много раз лучше, чем то, что сейчас делаете вы. Вам надо лишь сделать анимацию, которая будет в ресурсах проекта, дальше, по нужному триггеру/событию запускать ее.  Допустим вот [простая анимация](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25642760/6808809), где меняется Opacity, а затем видимость.

Comment: Всё верно, то что вы пытаетесь накостылять, WPF умеет из коробки. Учите WPF.